# Depth First Search Python Game Solver

Tags: python, depth-first-search

I have a basic maze game in python "*" are walls, "W" water buckets which allow you to travel through fire "F" (if you have none you lose), "A" is the player and " " is air and "X" and "Y" are start and endpoints. There are also numbers from 1 - 9 which have 1 other matching number so the player can teleport. Example map:

```
*X**********
*   1 W   F*
* FFFF  1  *
**********Y*
```

So I have a graph (dictionary) where I go through each character in the maze and find their neighbours like `{"0,0": [None, "0,1", None, "0,1"]}`

```
{"node": "LeftNeighbour", "RightNeighbour", "NeighbourAbove", "NeighbourBelow"}
```

and I am using coordinates `"x,y"` to denote neighbours.

Then the DFS code is ...

```
visited = []
def DFS_recursive(graph, node, nodeToFind):
    global visited
    for neighbour in graph[node]:
        if neighbour == nodeToFind:
            visited.append(neighbour)
            break
        if neighbour not in visited and neighbour != None:

            # get x and y by breaking up the string
            x = ""
            y = ""
            yFlag = False
            for char in neighbour:
                if char == ",":
                    yFlag = True
                elif yFlag == False:
                    x += str(char)
                else:
                    y += str(char)
            x, y = int(x), int(y)

            if grid[y][x].display == "*": # if the neighbour's display property is a wall, append the neighbour but don't call the function again ...
                visited.append(neighbour)
            else:
                visited.append(neighbour)
                DFS_recursive(graph, neighbour, nodeToFind)
```

So this works until I add teleport pad code.

```
if neighbour == (number from 1 - 9):
     find the coordinates of the other teleport pad and make the coordinates the new node
     DFS_recursive(graph, newNode, nodeToFind)
```

And yes I haven't added in the "nodeToFind" bit yet, couldn't quite get that to work so I added a separate function to deal with that. Probably should remove the parameter but anyway that's not the point.

So 1. Not sure if this is the right way to go about it (am new to programming)
and 2. No idea how to handle the teleport pads.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: most of your code is pseudocode, and also your actual variables/graph making process are missing. Is the grid stored in a 2-d array?

Comment: There's only one small piece of pseudocode. The graph making process works so I didn't include it, I just wrote above. It's a dictionary with a string key and list of strings as the elements of the key.

Comment: Add complete re-producible code, otherwise it's not of much use anyway. Also your dfs looks pretty unclear.

Comment: It's really not? ... it takes a node, looks through the neighbours. If it's not a "*", then this becomes the new node. Pretty simple.